# Notification when it hits bottom of screen

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, sprite-kit

I need to get notifications when my SKSpriteNode hits the bottom of the screen how can i get this?

i've created a:

```
     self.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithEdgeLoopFromRect:self.frame];
```

and the 2 bitmask categories. one for the mover and one for the edges at the screens.

```
    mover.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = moverCategory;
    self.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = worldCategory;

    mover.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = worldCategory;
```

This will get notifications when the mover also hit top edge. How can i limit this to only the bottom edge of the screen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest solution would be to just create a new node, assign a physics body to it with your required properties and place it at the bottom.